# Is there any subsitute of json_encode(PHP) in coldfusion?

Tags: php, json, coldfusion

I have used ColdFusion `SerializeJSON(queryname)` to convert the my query result in json format and got the result below:

```
{ 
  "COLUMNS":["ID","TAG","TAG_DESCRIPTION","TYPE"]
  , "DATA": [1,"PHP","PHP is an open-source server-side scripting language widely used in web development.","programming"]
}
```

But I want json this format, which is what PHP `json_encode($rows)` returns:

```
[ { "ID":"1"
    , "0":"1"
    , "tag":"php" 
    , "1":"php","type":"programming"
    , "2":"programming"
    , "tag_description":"PHP is an open-source server-side scripting language widely used in web development."
    , "3":"PHP is an open-source server-side scripting language widely used in web development."
   } 
]
```

Is there any substitute of `json_encode(PHP)` in ColdFusion? or do I have to create this json format manually?

Thanks

Comment: You can get the results below only if you first [convert your query results to objects](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/757-Learning-ColdFusion-8-Javascript-Object-Notation-JSON-Part-I-Data-Conversion.htm).

Answer (score 4):

No, there's not a function in CFML to create a JSON packet in a format that PHP decided to use to represent the JSON serialisation of one of its internal data types, any more than there's a function in PHP to create JSON in a format Adobe arbitrarily decided to represent one of its internal data types as JSON.

You'll have to roll your own.

The JSON `json_encode()` is spitting out is a bit of a mess. What's the story with doubling the key/values up with both a numeric index and a string key? I can't quite work out how a second row would be represented, based on what you've given us there. Could you give us a few rows of fairly generic data encoded as JSON so we can see what PHP is doing?

I'm sure it's just a matter of looping over your CFML recordset, and then for each row's column values populate the numeric- / string-keyed properties as you go. Don't try to build the JSON by hand, build a native CFML struct (or an array of structs?), in the correct schema, then serialise *that* with `serializeJson()`.

Sorry to be a bit vague. If you can explain what it is PHP was thinking by serialising your record the way it's chosen to, I can better explain the CFML logic to achieve the same ends.

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfquery name="getQuery" datasource="tags_dsn" dbtype="ODBC" >  
                select field1, field2 from tablename
</cfquery>
```

if i am using  SerializeJSON(getQuery), get the below json format output:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID","NAME"],"DATA":[[1,"ABC"],[2,"Imperial"]]}

<!---Instead of using SerializeJSON(getQuery) to Change the getQuery result to json i am using the below way.--->

<cfset var aTmp = arraynew(1)>
<cfif #getQuery.recordcount# gt 0>
    <cfloop query="getQuery">
        <cfset coInfo = StructNew()>
        <cfset coInfo["id"]="#getQuery.field1#">
        <cfset coInfo["name"]="#getQuery.field2#">
        <cfset arrayAppend(aTmp,coInfo)>
    </cfloop>
<cfset jsondata =  SerializeJSON(aTmp)>
<cfoutput>#jsondata#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

So that the output json is :

```
[{"name":"ABC","id":1},{"name":"Imperial","id":2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have CF11:

```
 <cfcomponent>
    <cfprocessingDirective pageencoding="utf-8">
    <cfset this.name = "Curso">
    <cfset this.serialization.preservecaseforstructkey = true   >
    <cfset this.serialization.serializeQueryAs = "struct">
    </cfcomponent>
```

and you will use serializeJSON(query) in your cfm/cfc. or:

```
<cffunction name="estructura" access="remote"  returntype="any" >
<cfargument name="query" type="query" required="true" >

    <cfset columns = arguments.query.ColumnList>
    <cfset array = ArrayNew( 1 )>
        <cfloop query="#arguments.query#">
            <cfset query_ = structNew()>
            <cfloop list="#columns#" index="col">
                <cfset query_[lcase(col)] = arguments.query[col][arguments.query.CurrentRow]>
            </cfloop>
            <cfset array[arguments.query.CurrentRow] = query_>
        </cfloop>

<cfset data.data = array>

<cfreturn data>

</cffunction>
<cffunction name="prueba" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="JSON">

    <cfquery name="query">
        select * from rsosa.colaboradores
    </cfquery>


    <cfreturn estructura(query)>


</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout my jQuery plugin for parsing native CF Query returns. You can make a native remote call to a CFC, get back your data in ColdFusion's native JSON parsing (using the returnFormat: 'json' option in your ajax request), then pass your result through this plugin to get the standard name/value format you're expecting in so many other jQuery (and other) plugins. I have a similar parser for ExtJS data stores as well.

https://github.com/cutterbl/serializeCFJSON